# How to get all URL using WebView in android studio

Tags: java, url, android-studio, webview, android-webview

Good day to all,

I'm making a simple app(for practice purposes) that uses a WebView in android studio. I want my app to toast all the URL's that I enter/browse. Ex, When I open Facebook it will toast its URL and when I log-in to my account it will toast again my facebook account, sounds like that. Here's my code. I'm new to stuff thing, any suggestions or help will be highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

**xml layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.example.nevigrof.ymuc.Back_order">

        <WebView

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/webview1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Codes**

```
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_survey_form);

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        openURL();
    }

    private void openURL() {

        webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN | View.FOCUS_UP);
        webview.loadUrl("http:/https://www.facebook.com/");
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        String webUrl = webview.getUrl();
        Toast.makeText(Back_order.this, webUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in the url at  webview.loadUrl()

Answer (score 1):

I suppose MyWebViewClient inherits from WebViewClient; you should override
onPageStarted and/or onPageFinished in MyWebViewClient class.

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    // Toast
}
```

Have a look to :

[WebViewClient onPageFinished Android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

[Load an HTML document Android training](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html#load-html)

Comment: Sir this was awesome, It worked the way i wanted to, Thank you so much for your time and effort on helping me. I already clicked the up arrow for vote but it will only appears when I got 15 reps,

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are only displaying the toast once, when you first display facebook.com in the webview. You should add code to notify you if the webview has displayed another page (i.e. another URL). You can use [WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) or other code to check if a new page is loaded/being loaded.